# Linq queries in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this function below which is used to get those roles which are not already assigned. I have two list now.

One which has all the roles and the other one which has those roles which are already assigned to that user.

How do I return only those which are present in allRoles but not in alreadyHaveRoles?

```
  public dynamic GiveRolesWhichAreNotAssignedToThisUser(String token, String selectedUser, String selectedOrganization)
    {
        User u = InstaFood.Core.User.Get(selectedUser);
        var allRoles = RolesType.GetByOrganizationType(selectedOrganization).Select(i => new
        {
            ID = i.Id,
            Name = i.Name
        });

        var alreadyHaveRoles = u.GetUserRoles().Select(i => new
        {
            ID = i.roleTypeId,
            Name = ""        
        });

        return ?? // what should be done here?
    }
```

Can I compare them now given that both have same attributes now?

Comment: Can I ask who has voted i down and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to return the difference of two sequences, eg:

```
var difference=allRoles.Except(alreadyHaveRoles);
```

This assumes the two sequences contain items of the same type. The objects are checked for equality using their `Equals` implementation.

If you want to use your own equality comparison, you need to either have your objects implement IEquatable or create a custom EqualityComparer and use the [Except overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) that accepts a custom EqualityComparer.

In your case, you return two anonymous types that don't even have the same fields. A human would have to guess how to compare the two types, a computer will simply refuse to compile the code. If you consider two items equal if the IDs are equal, simply return the IDs, eg:

```
var allRoleIds = RolesType.GetByOrganizationType(selectedOrganization)
                          .Select(i => i.Id);
var assignedRoleIds = u.GetUserRoles().Select(i => i.roleTypeId);
var unassignedRoleIds=allRoleIds.Except(assignedRoleIds);
```

Retrieving the unassigned roles is trivial after that, just use:

```
var unassignedRoles=RolesType.GetByOrganizationType(selectedOrganization)
                             .Where(role=>unassingedRoleIds.Contains(role.Id);
```

Comment: I get this error when I do the Except thing, 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The two sequences must contain the same type. In your case you have two anonymous types that don't even contain the same fields. It's impossible to say whether two instances are the same in this case. If you want to compare using only IDs, simply return the IDs instead of anonymous types, then compare the sequences

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is I would need the name of unassigned roles as well. Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: Once you have the IDs you can get the data you need with a `Where` statement. Using an empty `Name` field means no objects will ever match unless the names are empty as well

Comment: So where should I put the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public dynamic GiveRolesWhichAreNotAssignedToThisUser(String token, String selectedUser, String selectedOrganization)
    {
        User u = InstaFood.Core.User.Get(selectedUser);
        var allRoles = RolesType.GetByOrganizationType(selectedOrganization).Select(i => new
        {
            ID = i.Id,
            Name = i.Name
        });

        var alreadyHaveRoles = u.GetUserRoles().Select(i => new
        {
            ID = i.roleTypeId,
            Name = ""        
        });

        return allRoles.Where(i=>!alreadyHaveRoles.Contains(i));
    }
```

Not tried but it should work

Comment: No it won't, unless all roles have empty names

Comment: It returns all of them.